# MongoDB: Rename Field in A Collection (Document and Subdocuments)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

Using MongoDB 3.6
I have document structure like below
`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d88"),
    "Equipments" : [ 
        {
            "InnerEquipments" : {
                "AssetId" : 678
            },
            "AssetID" : 456
        }
    ],
    "AssetID" : 123
}
```

I want rename the field from AssetID/AssetId to Asset_ID at all levels.
How can I do this with mongo shell.

Comment: You actually could not do that ( at *all levels* ) without iterating each document and recursively traversing that document and renaming the keys, then replacing each document ( or possibly dynamically constructing `$set` and `$unset` statements ). Would you care to be more specific? i.e Perhaps stating that your documents **always** have a consistent structure rather than just a blanket *"at all levels"* statement? If you can do that, then the task is much more simple.

Comment: Exactly, no specific structure. Equipments -> Equipments -> Equipments (Equipments may or may not have equipments, which in turn might have an array of equipments)

Comment: I actually mean is there *possiblly* 1. Field at top level, 2. Field in `Equipments` array member, 3. Field within `InnerEquipments` of each `Equipments` array; and **no other variations**. Point being a finite and *predictable* ( meaning there are not other *near infinite nesting* possibilities ) of a set number of *possible* places, is far more simple to achieve than a full recursive document traversal. And a lot more efficient too.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it takes time. This would be a one time activity. No definitive structure, else I would have just used rename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code can do the trick:

```
// Getting all documents from the collection
var data = db.collection.find({},{"_id":0}).toArray();

// Converting the data into JSON string
var string = JSON.stringify(data);

// Replacing all variations of assetid with Asset_ID
string = string.replace(/assetid/ig,"Asset_ID");

// Removing existing documents from collection
db.collection.remove({});

// Converting the string back to JSON array and inserting it into the DB
db.collection.insertMany(JSON.parse(string));
```

**Before:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d89e9ab0558a18dd9cfc03a"),
    "Equipments" : [ 
        {
            "InnerEquipments" : {
                "AssetId" : 678
            },
            "AssetID" : 456
        }
    ],
    "AssetID" : 123
}
```

**After:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d89eea80558a18dd9cfc03b"),
    "Equipments" : [
        {
            "InnerEquipments" : {
                "Asset_ID" : 678
            },
            "Asset_ID" : 456
        }
    ],
    "Asset_ID" : 123
}
```

Comment: I guess i can use this with little modifications. Instead of each document separately, export entire collection as text file. And make use of "AssetID:" so that it does not other fields or data.

Comment: @AshishBagaddeo Yes, certainly!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a script for this.
I have not tested it. Make changes accordingly.

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    if(doc['AssetID']) {
      doc['Asset_ID'] = doc['AssetID'];
      delete doc['AssetID'];
    } else if (doc['AssetId']) {
      doc['Asset_ID'] = doc['AssetId'];
      delete doc['AssetId']
    }
    if(doc.Equipments && doc.Equipments.length) {
      doc.Equipments.forEach(function(rec) {
        if(rec['AssetID']) {
          rec['Asset_ID'] = rec['AssetID'];
          delete rec['AssetID'];
        } else if (rec['AssetId']) {
          rec['Asset_ID'] = rec['AssetId'];
          delete rec['AssetId']
        }

        if(rec['InnerEquipments']['AssetID']) {
          rec['InnerEquipments']['Asset_ID'] = rec['InnerEquipments']['AssetID'];
          delete rec['InnerEquipments']['AssetID'];
        } else if (rec['InnerEquipments']['AssetId']) {
          rec['InnerEquipments']['Asset_ID'] = rec['InnerEquipments']['AssetId'];
          delete rec['InnerEquipments']['AssetId']
        }
      })
    }
    db.collection.update({'_id':doc._id},doc);
  });
```